# [Swift 4, Xcode 9, GCD]Data is loaded before ui is refreshed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, swift4

I'm trying to setup the scroll view AFTER all images are loaded. But whatever I try I get nothing loaded or images are loaded several times (if paste DispatchQueue.main.async in the end of the loop)

How can I call setupScrollView only once - after all images are downloaded?

That's the function for downloading:

```
func downloadImages(arrayOfURLS: [URL]) {

    var imagesForPost: [UIImage] = []
    print("Ссылок столько - ", arrayOfURLS.count)

    DispatchQueue.global().async() {

        for url in arrayOfURLS {
            ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: arrayOfURLS, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
                (image, error, url, data) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                imagesForPost.append(image!)
                print("How much images - ", imagesForPost.count)
            }

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.setupScrollView(arrayOfImages: imagesForPost)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `dispatchGroup` ,but first declare `imagesForPost` as instance variable

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()


    for url in arrayOfURLS {

         dispatchGroup.enter()
        ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: arrayOfURLS, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
            (image, error, url, data) in

           defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            self.imagesForPost.append(image!)
            print("How much images - ", imagesForPost.count)

        }

    }



   dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Both functions complete ")
     self.setupScrollView(arrayOfImages: self.imagesForPost)
   }
```

Comment: It didn't help. dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) is called BEFORE the data is loaded

Comment: ok can you try edit , i know it will block the main thread , so add DispatchQueue.global().async inside ImageDownloader , can you try it ???

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - my bad. I forgot to delete DispatchQueue.global().async() {...} when inserting dispatchGroup. Now everything works perfectly.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy coding =D